# AddForce with with a specific velocity depending on the distance between the mousse and the launchPoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem with the code.

```
public Transform Nut;
public Transform cannonPoint;
public bool canShoot = true;
Rigidbody2D nutRb;
public float forceVelocity;
public float maxTop, minBottom;

private void Start()
{
    nutRb = Nut.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Nut.gameObject.AddComponent<ColliderEventSystem>().TriggerEntered += NutResset;
}

private void NutResset(ColliderEventSystem eventTarget, Collider2D other)
{
    Nut.SetParent(transform);
    Nut.localPosition = cannonPoint.localPosition;
    nutRb.simulated = false;
    nutRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    canShoot = true;
}

void Update()
{
    var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    var dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    if (angle >= minBottom && angle <= maxTop)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canShoot)
            LaunchNut(dir);
    }
}

private void LaunchNut(Vector3 launchPoint)
{
    Nut.SetParent(null);
    canShoot = false;
    nutRb.simulated = true;
    Geom.launchObj(Nut.gameObject, cannonPoint.position, launchPoint, forceVelocity * 100);
}
```

The code goes fine, but I want forceVelocity to vary depending on the distance between cannonPoint and mouse position. For example, if the position of the mouse is higher then the forceVelocity is higher, so if the position of the mouse is smaller then the forceVelocity is smaller.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can use pythagoras for this. if you have the X and Y of both object, you can calculate the distance between them.

Comment: Yep.....something like?  forceVelocity = Vector3.Distance(cannonPoint.position, dir);

Comment: goes well....thank you

Comment: Exactly :) I was thinking to manually do the calculations but ofcourse you can use vector to get the distances.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply the force by the distance between the mouse and the launchPoint,
if I'm not wrong, you just need to add this:

```
Geom.launchObj(Nut.gameObject, cannonPoint.position, launchPoint, forceVelocity * dir.Magnitude);
```

And then tweak forceVelocity depending on the launch speed you want.